# Why is a check suite not being created for a forked PR?

Tags: github, github-api, github-webhook, github-app, github-check-run

I created a new [GitHub App](https://developer.github.com/v3/apps/) to perform [check runs](https://developer.github.com/v3/checks/runs/). I want it to be triggered on every PR. It is working great when I get a PR from a different branch in my repository. But, when someone forks my repo and makes a PR, my application's webhook never gets the [check suite requested](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#checksuiteevent) event which it uses to trigger a check run. Why? How can I change this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am experiencing the same thing.